# Promisify async waterfall callback method possible?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I got such code in node.js:

```
class MyClass
  myMethod: () ->
    async.waterfall [
      (next) ->
        # do async DB Stuff
        next null, res
      (res, next) ->
        # do other async DB Stuff
        next null, res
    ], (err, res) ->
        # return a Promise to the method Caller

myclass = new MyClass
myclass.myMethod()
       .then((res) ->
        # hurray!
       )
       .catch((err) ->
       # booh!
       )
```

Now how to `return a Promise to the method caller` from the `async waterfall` callback? How to promisify the `async` module or is this tautological?

**Solution**

Promisify the Class Method with `bluebird` like this:

```
 class MyClass
   new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
      myMethod: () ->
        async.waterfall [
          (next) ->
            # do async DB Stuff
            next null, res
          (res, next) ->
            # do other async DB Stuff
            next null, res
        ], (err, res) ->
            if err 
              reject err
            else
              resolve res
    )
```

Now the instantiated class method is thenable and catchable, in fact all these are available:

```
promise
  .then(okFn, errFn)
  .spread(okFn, errFn) //*
  .catch(errFn)
  .catch(TypeError, errFn) //*
  .finally(fn) //*
  .map(function (e) { ... })
  .each(function (e) { ... })
```

Comment: You want to transform all the code to a promise one, or you just want to return a promise? If its later, you can use `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { ... async.waterfall})`, and call `resove(res)` in done callback.

Comment: yes I figured already... updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that's coffeescript, you put it in the javascript tag.

You return it at the top:

```
myMethod: () ->
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) ->
    async.waterfall [
       # ...
    ], (err, result) ->
      if (err)
        reject(err)
      else
        resolve(result)
  )
```

Also look into IcedCoffeeScript and ES7 async/await.

Comment: ok changed tag. JS is just transpiled CS, and harder to read, the both go hand in hand I do not distinct them anymore, sorry for caused confusion. Is your solution thenable, e.g. is then and catch now implied and usable?

Comment: That Iced CS is pretty neat. Thanks for that. If using `.then` now, it does timeout in my tests..

Comment: Had a guard in my `if err`-reject block that blocked the resolving. All problems gone now, its perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying with Iced CoffeeScript is Promisfiying with Bluebird obsolete?

Comment: The thing is IcedCoffeeScript has been around for years even before promises became popular, and there is another ToffeeScript (eventually JS will probably look like ToffeeScript async ! syntax), and another LiveScript with backcalls and functional programming.. those are all better than standard JS, but now ES6 is very popular and ES7 is not so bad so you may consider using ES7 with babel, the majority are doing that.  Whatever you like, these days I use ES7 with babel because people accept it but don't like the other ones usually for some reason even though they are better.